# SQL Server speed up WHILE Loop with INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, t-sql, insert-into

SQL WHILE Loop is Slow with Insert Into.
Is there any way to speed up the query?

I want to insert 500,000 rows. If there is a commit after each 10,000 row will it be faster?

Example:

Insert rows from DB1 to DB2 and get primary autocrement key id from DB2 to DB1.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
    (
        ROWID int identity(1,1) primary key,
        Comp_Key_1 NVARCHAR(20),
        Comp_Key_2 NVARCHAR(256),
        Comp_Key_3 NVARCHAR(256)
    )
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Comp_Key_1, Comp_Key_2, Comp_Key_3) 
SELECT Comp_Key_1, Comp_Key_2, Comp_Key_3 FROM [DB1].[dbo].FILES


DECLARE @MAXID INT, @Counter INT, @Comp_Key_1 NCHAR(20), @Comp_Key_2 nvarchar(256), @Comp_Key_3 nvarchar(256), @id_current int,;
SET @COUNTER = 1
SELECT @MAXID = COUNT(*) FROM #Temp

WHILE (@COUNTER <= @MAXID)
        BEGIN

            set @Comp_Key_1= (select Comp_Key_1_doc from #Temp where ROWID= @COUNTER)
            set @Comp_Key_2= (select Comp_Key_2_doc from #Temp where ROWID= @COUNTER)
            set @Comp_Key_3= (select Comp_Key_3_doc from #Temp where ROWID= @COUNTER)

            INSERT INTO [DB2].[dbo].[ADDRESS] (STREET,STREET_FROM,STREET_TO)
            SELECT STREET,STREET_FROM,STREET_TO
            FROM [DB1].[dbo].[ADDRESS]
            WHERE [DB1].[dbo].[ADDRESS].Comp_Key_1= @Comp_Key_1
               and [DB1].[dbo].[ADDRESS].Comp_Key_2=@Comp_Key_2
               and [DB1].[dbo].[ADDRESS].Comp_Key_3=@Comp_Key_3;

            set @id_current = IDENT_CURRENT('[DB2].[dbo].[ADDRESS]')

            update [DB1].[dbo].[ADDRESS]
            set id=@id_current
            where @Comp_Key_1=[ADDRESS].Comp_Key_1
              and @Comp_Key_2=[ADDRESS].Comp_Key_2
              and @Comp_Key_3=[ADDRESS].Comp_Key_3;

        SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1


      END 
    COMMIT
```

DB2 has a primary autocrement key, want to be transfered in DB1 after each row inserted. DB1 has a composite key of 3 columns. 
The design of DB2 doesn't include the composite key.

[example of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYZEY.jpg)

Is there any way to speed up the insert?

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results help.

Comment: Perhaps the first thing to look at for performance is to try to avoid the while loop.

Comment: You are doing 3 selects, one insert and one update 500.000 times? Your solution is removing the loop.

Comment: i uploaded an image as an example. If i remove loop, how will i know in which row in DB1 will the id be updated? The design of DB2 doesn't inclued the foreign keys, and don't want to..DB2 has the primary autocrement key that i want to be transfered in DB1 after insert of each row.. Is there a way without loop?

Comment: Use a `MERGE` statement with an `OUTPUT` clause to retrieve the identity values of the inserted records all at once, so you can match them to update later.

Comment: INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE also have [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clauses. Write a single INSERT statement to load everything into the first table and insert the generated IDs into a staging/temporary table with `INSERT ... OUTPUT inserted.ID,inserted.Comp_Key_1 ... INTO someTable`. Join with table in the UPDATE statement

Comment: thank you  Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: How does the loop change `set @id_current  =  IDENT_CURRENT('[DB2].[dbo].[ADDRESS]')` ?

Comment: paparazzo, if i understand the question, it gets the generated ID from DB2, for each loop, into a variable, in order to insert the value then in  DB1.

Comment: Aside: [`IDENT_CURRENT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns a value without regard to session or scope. It is rarely the appropriate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate the help!

I used **MERGE** statement with an **OUTPUT** clause, as suggested,  inserted the generated IDs and the initial composite key into a temporary table in order to update later with join.

Very efficient (took only 15 minutes) and there was no need for loop. Thank you!

This is the code:

```
BEGIN TRAN
CREATE TABLE #TempInserted
    (inserted_id int,Comp_Key_1 NVARCHAR(20), Comp_Key_2 NVARCHAR(256), Comp_Key_3 NVARCHAR(256))

MERGE [DB2].[dbo].[ADDRESS] AS T  -- target table T
USING (SELECT STREET,STREET_FROM,STREET_TO, Comp_Key_1,Comp_Key_2, Comp_Key_3
       FROM [DB1].[dbo].[ADDRESS] AS M ) S  -- source table S
ON 0=1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (STREET,STREET_FROM,STREET_TO) -- target table T
    VALUES (STREET,STREET_FROM,STREET_TO) -- source table S

OUTPUT inserted.id, S.Comp_Key_1, S.Comp_Key_2, S.Comp_Key_3 
INTO #TempInserted(inserted_id,Comp_Key_1,Comp_Key_2,Comp_Key_3);

update [DB1].[dbo].[ADDRESS]
set id=#TempInserted.inserted_id 
FROM [BankMasterDB_migration].[dbo].LOANNUMBER AS M
JOIN #TempInserted ON M.Comp_Key_1=#TempInserted.Comp_Key_1
                  AND M.Comp_Key_2=#TempInserted.Comp_Key_2
                  AND M.Comp_Key_3=#TempInserted.Comp_Key_3

COMMIT
```